# TI-83 Create List of invNorm in L2 from values in L1

Tags: statistical-inference, calculator

I need to make a Q-Q plot from values in L1 list, but I need to get the invNorm(x) value of each number and put it into another list, L2. Do I need to call the invNorm function for each number in L1, or is there a shortcut where I can do the function for each value in L1 and place it into L2?

Answer (score 0):

The `invNorm(` command won't thread over lists directly for you, but you can get the same effect with `seq(invNorm(L₁(N)),N,1,dim(L₁))→L₂`.

(See [this page](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/seq-list) for more details on the `seq(` command.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll play with that a bit, but it looks like it should do the trick.